# Start activity from notification and run some code automatic

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

Need some help.
I have a notification that when touch opens one activity.
Inside that activity i have a map with some types of view (not by default, i need to press a button to get that extra views).
What i want to do is everytime i touch notification my activity open with one certain view (one of the ones i need to press to view).

By other words i need my activity to be open and automatic run the code that leads to one specific view but only when the activity starts from  my notification.

My notification code:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mapa.class);
```

The code i need to run to get my view after the activity is loaded:

```
   mLocationDisplay.setAutoPanMode(LocationDisplay.AutoPanMode.RECENTER);
                if (!mLocationDisplay.isStarted())
                    mLocationDisplay.startAsync();
                break;
```

Comment: Have you tried including an extra in your notification intent?
Then inside your activity you can use `getIntent().getExtra(...) ` to check if activity was triggered from notificatoin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with by pass a value from the intent like that

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mapa.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION",true);
```

and on your activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        boolean isFromNotification = 
        intent.getBooleanExtra("IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION",false);
        if (isFromNotification){
            //call the method
mLocationDisplay.setAutoPanMode(LocationDisplay.AutoPanMode.RECENTER);
                if (!mLocationDisplay.isStarted())
                    mLocationDisplay.startAsync();
        }
    }
```

this line mean             `intent.getBooleanExtra("IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION",false);`

get value that passed with key `"IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION"` if the value exists return the value otherwise return default value in this example i chose the default value to be false

Comment: Perfect, it works! Many thks Assadi!Just one correction:
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mapa.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION",true);